# Sql Table Subgrouping upon Values

Tags: sql-server, database, grouping, partitioning

I've vehicle tracking data, I want to create Vehicle stoppage report. Help me to write sql query for that. Actual Data and resultant data are like Table1 and Table2 respectively.

[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not good in writing sql queries, I already tried my best but no success.

Comment: which version of sql do you use? SELECT  @@VERSION

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is some working statement

```
declare @t TABLE(id INT, dt DATETIME, sp int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:05', 12)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:06', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:07', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:08', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:09', 5)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:10', 8)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:11', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:12', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:13', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1, '2015-01-17 12:00:14', 7)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:05', 10)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:06', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:07', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:08', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:09', 12)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:10', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:11', 0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2, '2015-01-17 12:00:12', 10)




;
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   a.id ,
                        a.dt AS stdt ,
                        b.dt AS endt ,
                        a.sp ,
                        a.rn
               FROM     ( SELECT    * ,
                                    1
                                    + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ) AS n ,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY GETDATE() ) AS rn
                          FROM      @t t1
                        ) a
                        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  * ,
                                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ) AS n
                                    FROM    @t t1
                                  ) b ON b.id = a.id
                                         AND b.n = a.n
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   t1.id ,
                        t1.stdt ,
                        ISNULL(t1.endt, GETDATE()) AS endt ,
                        t1.sp ,
                        t1.rn ,
                        SUM(t2.sp) AS sum
               FROM     cte1 t1
                        INNER JOIN cte1 t2 ON t1.rn >= t2.rn
               GROUP BY t1.id ,
                        t1.stdt ,
                        t1.endt ,
                        t1.sp ,
                        t1.rn
             )
    SELECT  id ,
            MIN(stdt) ,
            MAX(stdt) ,
            DATEDIFF(ss, MIN(stdt), MAX(stdt)) 
    FROM    cte2
    WHERE   sp = 0
    GROUP BY id ,
            SUM
```

Here is result

```
1   2015-01-17 12:00:06.000 2015-01-17 12:00:08.000 2
1   2015-01-17 12:00:11.000 2015-01-17 12:00:13.000 2
2   2015-01-17 12:00:06.000 2015-01-17 12:00:08.000 2
2   2015-01-17 12:00:10.000 2015-01-17 12:00:11.000 1
```

You have result for vehicle 1 `12:06 to 12:08`. But i really think that results should be `12:06 to 12:09`. If so, just change

```
SELECT  id ,
                MIN(stdt) ,
                MAX(stdt) ,
                DATEDIFF(ss, MIN(stdt), MAX(stdt))
        FROM    cte2
        WHERE   sp = 0
        GROUP BY id ,
                SUM
```

to

```
SELECT  id ,
            MIN(stdt) ,
            MAX(endt) ,
            DATEDIFF(ss, MIN(stdt), MAX(endt))
    FROM    cte2
    WHERE   sp = 0
    GROUP BY id ,
            SUM
```

Comment: Another issue with me, if you can help me out... I'm using this query on a large datatable where lacs of new records are being generated everyday. On that the response time of query is very high in minutes.

Can there be any optimization so the the response time can be decreased up to less than a minute?

Thanks & Regards